# Angular 10 SVG getBBox() returns incorrect values

Tags: angular

I have a template like this.

```
<svg #connectorSVG [style.width.px]="diagramConnector.Width" [style.height.px]="diagramConnector.Height" >
  <g class="diagram-item-connector-line-path" >
    <path [attr.d]="diagramConnector.ConnectorPath" pointer-events="visibleStroke" fill="none" stroke-width="2"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And here is how I'm calling getBox()

```
@ViewChild('connectorSVG', { static: false }) connectorSVG: ElementRef;
resetPath(path: string) {
  this.diagramConnector.ConnectorPath = path;
  let rect = this.connectorSVG.nativeElement.getBBox();
  this.diagramConnector.Height = rect.height;
  this.diagramConnector.Width = rect.width;
}
```

As you can see, I'm binding [attr.d] with the property diagramConnector.ConnectorPath.

And here is the problem.

I call #connectorSVG.getBox() right after the value of diagramConnector.ConnectorPath is changed to update the SVG width and height. But sometimes I get correct width and height, and sometimes I get incorrect width and height from #connectorSVG.getBox().

But when I call #connectorSVG.getBox() after a second later, it always returns the correct width and height.

I tried getBoundingClientRect(), but it has the same behavior.

Is this because it takes some time to bind with the property and update the DOM? If so, how do I know when the binding is complete, and DOM is updated after the property value is changed?

Or are there other reasons why there is a delay? and how can I always get the correct value?

FYI, I cannot use afterviewinit, because the path constantly changes after the view initialization.

Comment: Show please `getBox()`. If this method prepares width, height, so problem in this

Comment: OK. I just added the code where I call getBBox().